# SwiftUI in Xcode 12 Beta 3 - Picker is disabled when presenting a view as a Sheet

Tags: swiftui, xcode12

The following code presents the same view PatientView in 2 ways:

1. As a Sheet
2. NavigationLink

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach(patients, id: \.self) { patient in
                        NavigationLink(destination:
                                        PatientView(selectedPatient: patient, isDependant: false, mainID: "")) {
                            PatientRowView(patient: patient)
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete { indexSet in
                        for index in indexSet {
                            self.moc.delete(self.patients[index])
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                    self.showingAddScreen.toggle()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                })
                .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddScreen) {
                    PatientView(selectedPatient: nil, isDependant: false, mainID: "").environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Patients")
                .background(NavigationConfigurator { nc in
                    nc.navigationBar.barTintColor = .launchpadBackgroundGray
                    nc.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : UIColor.black]
                })
        }
    }
```

When presented as a Sheet the Pickers on the PatientView are disabled:

[image: PatientView Presented as a Sheet]

But when presented through the Navigationlink the pickers work as expected:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening? Any solutions to make the pickers were properly when presented as a Sheet would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Form` picker requires `NavigationView` so provide it for sheet workflow explicitly

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showingAddScreen) {
  NavigationView {
    PatientView(selectedPatient: nil, isDependant: false, 
        mainID: "").environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your solution. I also found a different solution here https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-fix-a-form-picker-or-a-navigationlink-that-isnt-tappable. But it basically boils down to the same thing. I used your solution. Thanks again.